# Can't run x11vnc as a service

Tags: services, vnc

I am trying to configure an x11vnc server on Ubuntu 20.04. When I start it from the terminal with the command:

```
x11vnc -noxdamage -display :0 -rfbport 5900 -rfbauth /home/km/.vnc/passwd -forever -loop
```

this is no problem and the server starts and I can connect from another machine.

In this case, I wanted to start this service at system startup and so I created a file `/lib/systems/system/x1vnc.service` with the contents:

```
[Unit].
Description=x11vnc service
After=display-manager.service network.target syslog.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -noxdamage -display :0 -rfbport 5900 -rfbauth /home/km/.vnc/passwd -forever -loop
ExecStop=/usr/bin/killall x11vnc
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But when I start this service via `sudo systemctl start x11vnc.service` I can see that the server is trying to start nonstop in a loop and I can't connect to it, sample status output:

```
km@km-Z97-HD3:~$ sudo systemctl status x11vnc.service
● x11vnc.service - x11vnc service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/x11vnc.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-08-24 11:24:22 CEST; 19min ago
   Main PID: 71782 (x11vnc)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 38269)
     Memory: 1.2M
     CGroup: /system.slice/x11vnc.service
             └─71782 /usr/bin/x11vnc -noxdamage -display :0 -rfbport 5900 -rfbauth /home/km/.vnc/passwd -forever -loop

sie 24 11:43:27 km-Z97-HD3 x11vnc[72438]:    Sometimes the command "ps wwwwaux | grep auth" can reveal the file location.
sie 24 11:43:27 km-Z97-HD3 x11vnc[72438]:    Starting with x11vnc 0.9.9 you can have it try to guess by using:
sie 24 11:43:27 km-Z97-HD3 x11vnc[72438]: -auth guess
sie 24 11:43:27 km-Z97-HD3 x11vnc[72438]: (see also the x11vnc -findauth option.).
sie 24 11:43:27 km-Z97-HD3 x11vnc[72438]:    Only root will have read permission for the file, and so x11vnc must be run
sie 24 11:43:27 km-Z97-HD3 x11vnc[72438]: as root (or copy it).  The random characters in the filenames will of course
sie 24 11:43:27 km-Z97-HD3 x11vnc[72438]: change and the directory the cookie file resides in is system dependent.
sie 24 11:43:27 km-Z97-HD3 x11vnc[72438]: See also: http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/faq.html
sie 24 11:43:27 km-Z97-HD3 x11vnc[71782]: --- x11vnc loop: sleeping 2000 ms ---.
sie 24 11:43:29 km-Z97-HD3 x11vnc[71782]: --- x11vnc loop: 457 ---
```

How to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the Xauthority. Did you try -auth guess as mentioned in the output. I'm guessing that wont work either. I'm running Kubuntu 22.04 and have a solution that works for it but likely not on Gnome. I start with a bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Restart the x11vnc service
restartx11vnc () {
    /usr/bin/systemctl restart x11vnc
}

# Log a message to the system log
logtosyslog () {
    /usr/bin/logger -t startx11vnc $1
}

# Log startup
logtosyslog "x11vnc starting"

# Start up x11vnc in the background. If it exits (-loop exits) then we'll try to recover by restarting.
# The & at the end lets the first line run in the background. Restarting the service will kill it. Commands are
# chained with  ;  because we want all the commands to be executed if x11vnc exitsno matter what the return status.
# Putting the commands in the next 3 lines between parentheses allows the & at the end run all the commands in a
# subshell as a group which also allows the second part of the script to go ahead and run.
( /usr/bin/x11vnc -auth /var/run/sddm/* -loop -forever -repeat -shared -display :0 -rfbauth /etc/x11vnc.pass -rfbport 5900 -oa /var/log/x11vnc.log ; \
logtosyslog "x11vnc exited, restarting" ; \
restartx11vnc ) &

# A second thread is started because of the & at the end of the last line and this thread will wait for a new file
# to be created in /var/run/sddm. This indicates that a user has logged off and a new Xauthority has been generated
/usr/bin/inotifywait -qq -e create /var/run/sddm

# Wait to make sure the new Xauthority is fully set up
/usr/bin/sleep 2

# Log the change
logtosyslog "The Xauthority file changed, restartting x11vnc"

# Restart the x11vnc service so that the new Xauthority is used
restartx11vnc
```

and my service file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run x11vnc at startup
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
#If you start x11vnc this way, every time a user logs off he won’t be able to log back in until the service is restarted 
#ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/x11vnc -auth /var/run/sddm/* -forever -loop -repeat -noxdamage -shared -display :0 -rfbauth /etc/x11vnc.pass -rfbport 5900 -o /var/log/x11vnc.log"
ExecStart=/bin/bash /usr/bin/startx11vnc

Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

/var/run/sddm/ may or may not be where the Xauthority is when ***your*** greeter starts. It works for KDE and SDDM. The rest of the code in the script takes care of the fact that when you logoff the Xauthority file changes and x11vnc has to be reloaded to use the new token. Oh, you also need to install inotify-tools, ***sudo apt install inotify-tools*** to detect the file change. Good luck!